# Deploy several Java applications on Google App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Google Cloud Platform new user here.

I'd like to deploy several Java web applications (Spring Boot apps actually) to Google App Engine **while remaining Always Free compatible**.

My question is about the relation between projects and applications.

I know how to deploy an application to a project, such as "myproject". Then the resulting URL is "myproject.appspot.com" (port does not seem customizable).

I need to deploy a second application, I guess I **have** to use another project (since the apps can't have the same URL). Would be tedious.

Is that so ? **Do I have to create a GCP project for each of my Java web applications in GAE** ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find most of the information here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine.

You can either create a new project or create a new app engine service (originally called module).
By default you deploy to app engine on the "default" service, but you can specify another service name to create or update another one.

For the URLs, you should check this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed

myservice-dot-myproject.appspot.com will point directly to the specific service in the project but you can use the main project hostname or a custom domain with path prefix redirections as well.

**Separate projects**

They will save you some money because you will have a free tier for each app.

**Separate services in a single project**

They are easier to maintain and connect together and they can share data through the datastore, but they share one free tier and they each have their own app engine instances so the cost will add up pretty fast if you have a lot of low traffic services.